# Transform SOAP to HTML using XSLT (error parsing)

Tags: xslt, soap

I tried to transform a SOAP response message to HTML using XSLT, but it does not work.

The 'instance' tag has some attributes, when I retrieve them, my code works fine.

**My SOAP response message :**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <RetrieveIncidentListResponse 
            message="Success" 
            returnCode="0" 
            schemaRevisionDate="2018-12-19" 
            schemaRevisionLevel="0" 
            status="SUCCESS" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7" 
            xmlns:cmn="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7/Common" 
            xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7/Incident.xsd">
            <instance query="" recordid="I003988322 - incident chatBot" uniquequery="number=&quot;I003988322&quot;">
                <TicketID type="String">I003988322</TicketID>
            </instance>
            <instance query="" recordid="I003988323 - incident chatBot" uniquequery="number=&quot;I003988323&quot;">
                <TicketID type="String">I003988323</TicketID>
            </instance>
        </RetrieveIncidentListResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**My XSLT code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:p="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7"
    exclude-result-prefixes="p">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="//p:RetrieveIncidentListResponse/p:instance">
            <tr>
                <td>TicketID : </td><td><xsl:value-of select="p:TicketID"/></td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        Nb tickets: <xsl:value-of select="count(//p:RetrieveIncidentListResponse/p:instance)"/>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual result:

```
Nb tickets: 0
```

Expected result:

```
TicketID :  I003988322
TicketID :  I003988323
Nb tickets: 2
```

Comment: Your input sample lacks a closing tag for the element `SOAP-ENV:Envelope`, if I correct the input your code at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9H displays what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't find any missing closing tag on my code. But I tried to use your parser (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/) and It works fine. 

But I still have the same problem when I tried to use my parser (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog)
I copy paste the code you give me but I doesn't work

Comment: Then that tool is broken, ask the owners to fix it.

Comment: Ok. I will use the xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net tool.
Thank you.

Comment: w3schools is not generally known as a great place, so I would not trust their tool. xsltfiddle gives the correct response, what seems to be happening with w3schools is that &quot; entities are expanded so that your attributes uniquequery="number=&quot;I003988323&quot;" are actually being interpreted as uniquequery="number=" I003988323""> which is of course a syntax error, so for me W3Schools tells me 
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt_result.asp etc. etc.

Comment: Great 
Thank you for these explanation.